# Qt5 QStyledItemDelegate on a QListView removes all the default style

Tags: c++, qt5, qstyleditemdelegate

I have some `QIcon` and `QString` pairs displayed in a `QListview`. The whole thing has been set up using the Qt Model/View Programming.

I am displaying labeled icons in this `QListView`. Items are displayed using the `IconMode`, `Snap` and `TopToBottom` flags. Thus, these are organised into a grid.

I would like to layout all the `QListView` items vertically and centered. In order to do this, I subclassed the `QStyledItemDelegate` object, and overloaded the paint method. However, I have three main problems:

1. Icon labels have been moved (in the `QStyledItemDelegate` subclasses) and a dotted square appears at its original place.
2. All the default styles are gone (hover, selection). I know how I can add some again, but I would like to use the default one (Windows style).
3. Everything is rendered into a grid, even if `setGridSize` is not called. I would like to use only one "column".

Here is a piece of code:

- An extract of the constructor of my custom `QListView`:

> ```
> setViewMode(QListView::IconMode);
> setMovement(QListView::Snap);
> setFlow(QListView::TopToBottom);
> setSpacing(5);
> setIconSize(QSize(iconSize, iconSize));
> setGridSize(QSize(iconSize + 10, iconSize + 10));
> setDragEnabled(true);
> setAcceptDrops(true);
> setDropIndicatorShown(true);
> ```

- The paint method of the `QStyledItemDelegate`:

> ```
> void FramesStyledItemDelegate::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const
> {
>     QStyleOptionViewItemV4 opt = option;
>     //initStyleOption(&opt, index);
>
>     opt.icon = QIcon();
>     opt.text = QString();
>
>     QApplication::style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ItemViewItem, &opt, painter);
>
>     const QRect r = option.rect;
>
>     QIcon icon = qvariant_cast<QIcon>(index.data(Qt::DecorationRole));
>     QString string = qvariant_cast<QString>(index.data(Qt::DisplayRole));
>     QPixmap pix = icon.pixmap(r.size());
>
>     const QPoint p = QPoint((r.width() - pix.width())/2, (r.height() - pix.height())/2);
>
>     painter->drawPixmap(r.topLeft() + p, pix);
>     painter->drawText(r.center() + p + QPoint(-(string.count() / 2), r.height() / 2), string);
> }
> ```

- If I do not use the `initStyleOption` shown above, I can remove the
  dotted square, but I lose all the default styles.
- If I uncomment the `initStyleOption`, The dotted square appears. I also lose all the default styles.

Here are some screenshots:

[image: No decoration]

The cursor is on item 0 (No hover decoration, no selection decoration).

[image]

Item 0 has been selected. A small dotted square appears (`initStyleOption` has been uncommented).

[image]

I have switched to the `ListMode`. Selection decoration is working but not hover. Again, a small dotted square appears at the original place of the label.

Does someone have an idea? Thanks for your answers.